# Database re-provisioning failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Trying to create data sync between 2 databases one on my local computer and the other is on Azure cloud, after creating sync agent and sync group and adding the needed tables to be synced an error appears preventing the sync process.

Database re-provisioning failed with the exception "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. Inner exception: SqlException ID: 92d7c5bf-96c9-4c43-a578-0cb9b678b044, Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:468, Message: SQL error with code 468 For more information, provide tracing ID ‘954e4a9d-f025-4919-a9cc-5f32e9e620e6’ to customer support."

Any help how to solve this?

Comment: You can modify the `collation` of your database according to the prompt of my answer, make the collation value of `Azure SQL DB` and `local DB` consistent, and then perform sync operation.

Comment: I changed both to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but i still  get the same error.

Comment: Okey, I got it. It is recommended to try to use other tools to synchronize the two databases and perform the same operations as in your code to see if there are any error messages. You can use Navicat or SSMS. In this way, we can locate that there may be a problem with a certain step of operation.

Answer (score 0):

*How to change Collation by SSMS.*

1. Choose your db, right click
2. find options, and select a collation from the Collation drop-down list
3. find `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, then click ok button.

The default collation value of Azure SQL DB is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. You can change your local server's collation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#is-collation-supported-in-sql-data-sync) provides the guidance regarding the collation in DataSync. It really depends on the way you do the sync. Here is what it says:
[image]

Please review the same and if you have any further question or need any further help, please get back to us.

Thanks
Navtej S